# Pan image in lightroom with keyboard

Tags: lightroom, keyboard-shortcuts

When I'm going through a whole bunch of shots to determine which to delete and which to flag, it's fastest for me to just keep both hands on the keyboard.  However, if I want to zoom in to 100% on a picture and then pan to a specific area, it seems I can only get halfway there -- 'Z' to zoom, but then I'm stuck having to pick up the mouse to pan around.

I was excited to find page-up/page-down/home/end can be used, but they seem to exist to provide an exhaustive, linear scrolling of the image, panning top-to-bottom then left-to-right, without unconstrained 2d movement.

Is there some way to toggle the arrow keys so they can pan instead of navigate to the next/prev photo?  Something else?  Or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 1):

Right after posting this, I found that `shift` will modify page-up/down to invert its movement -- while holding shift, page-up/down move left-to-right then top-to-bottom.  It kind of warps my mind to try to translate my brain's panning requests into the appropriate shift/up/down combination, but it's possible so I may just need to get used to it.